# Data Selected form MySQL db not displaying

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having trouble unpacking data from MySQL.

Here is my code

```
if($result){

 $sql_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  `application` ORDER BY  `application`.`app_id`               
 DESC LIMIT 0 , 1");
 $row = mysql_fetch_row($sql_result); 
 echo $row['app_id'];

  }

  else {
  echo "ERROR";
  }
```

This should echo the app_id but, the page is just returning blank. Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: Try `$row[0]['app_id']`

Comment: [The `mysql_xxx` functions are deprecated. Do not use them for new code.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944956/the-mysql-extension-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-the-future-use-mysqli)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it to

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result);
```

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_fetch_row()` will return result as numerical array. So you need to fetch the result with index like `$row[0]`. If you are using `mysql_fetch_array()`, it will result an associative array where you can either use numerical index or field index as `$row['app_id']`.

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_fetch_row ($result )` Returns a numerical array that corresponds to the fetched row and moves the internal data pointer ahead.

use `echo $row['0'];` instead of  `echo $row['app_id'];`